# Click to edit multiple forms fields using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one form and fields are firstname, lastname, email, country, with edit icon and submit and cancel button.

when the user clicked on the edit icon(Top right corner) then all the values will display in the textbox and country will display in the select dropdown.

I tried some code but I am getting the all the values in the single field and values are displaying multiple times.

Would you help me in this?

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
 var text = $('.text-info').text();
 var input = $('<input id="attribute" type="text" value="' + text + '" />')
 $('.text-info').text('').append(input);
 input.select();
 $('.btn').show();
 $('#edit').hide();
});
```

```css
.width-400{width: 400px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 20px;}
.border{border:1px solid #000;}
input{margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;}
  .btn{display:flex;margin-top: 10px;display: none;}
  .font-icon{text-align: right;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="border width-400">
 <div class="font-icon"><a class="edit" href="#" id="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
 <form method="post" action="update.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname" class="control-label">Firstname:</label><spa class="text-info">Narendra</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname" class="control-label">Lastname:</label><span class="text-info">verma</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email:</label><span class="text-info">abc@gmail.com</span>
</div>
    <select>
   <option value="">Choose country</option>
   <option>India</option>
   <option>USA</option>
   <option>UK</option>
  </select>
 <div class="btn">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="cancel">
 </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    $('#edit').click(function() {
     var text = $('.text-info').each(function (index,oneSpan){
                var input = $('<input type="text" value="' + $(oneSpan).text() + '" />')
     $(oneSpan).text('').append(input);
});
 

var country = $('.select-info').text();
  $('.select-info').hide();
  $('#select-elm').val(country).show();
 $('.btn').show();
 $('#edit').hide();
    });
```

```css
.width-400{width: 400px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 20px;}
.border{border:1px solid #000;}
input{margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;}
  .btn{display:flex;margin-top: 10px;display: none;}
  .font-icon{text-align: right;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="border width-400">
 <div class="font-icon"><a class="edit" href="#" id="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
 <form method="post" action="update.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname" class="control-label">Firstname:</label><span class="text-info">Narendra</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname" class="control-label">Lastname:</label><span class="text-info">verma</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email:</label><span class="text-info">abc@gmail.com</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country" class="control-label">Country:</label><span class="select-info">USA</span>
</div>
    <select id="select-elm" >
   <option value="">Choose country</option>
   <option>India</option>
   <option>USA</option>
   <option>UK</option>
  </select>
 <div class="btn">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="cancel">
 </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Now what did you miss**
first `$('.text-info')` you are selecting all node that have this so it must return an king of array calling the method `text()` on it will just concatene them so you got a string with all your values.
after you created you input and again `$('.text-info').text('').append(input);` just another array returned by the text method so the append one will be executed in all the element you end with a long str contained in an input this last appended in all your span.

**What we did**

we are getting an array from the $('.text-info') just call `each(function(){}` on it we will get all our span one by one.
So just create an input fetch the value from our ONE SPAN. empty this one and just push your array on it

Comment: sorry for late reply, There was some internet issue at my home, Your code is working but I just want to know how to use for select dropdown

Comment: I dont understand what do you want to do with the select dropdown be more clear please

Comment: because I am using a select dropdown for the country.I have to display the country name like Country: India then after clicked on edit icon user can change the all the fields

Comment: That's I need. It's working perfectly, Thanks for the help.(I just set the display: none for the select tag so it'll not display the first time.  After clicking on edit icon then it will display) Upvote from my side